# Random error when connecting to SAP with ERPConnect

Tags: c#, asp.net, sap-erp, sap-r3, erpconnect

We use ERPConnect in our ASP.NET application but sometimes we get some error messages when users try to connect to SAP through our application.

> CPIC-CALL: 'CMRCV : rc=19 LOCATION SAP-Gateway on host SERVERNAME / sapgw10 ERROR Conversation 53230591 not found TIME Wed Nov 16 13:49:58 2011 RELEASE 701 COMPONENT SAP-Gateway VERSION 2 RC 728 MODULE gwxxrd.c LINE 6278 COUNTER 1277701

It always happens when opening a connection to SAP through ERPConnect.

```
R3Connection connection = Connection;
connection.Open(); // the error occurs here
```

It's quite random. Some days we don't get any error message, other days we get 20 messages a day.
ERPConnect uses librfc32.dll defined in the System32-folder and has version 7200.1.39.6461 (which is a recent version).

This issue didn't occur on my local development machine (Windows 7 x86). It always occurs on our production server (Windows Server 2008 R2).

Any idea what could cause this issue?

**Edit (added error log extract):**

> ---
>
> ```
> *                                                                                                                               
> *  LOCATION    SAP-Gateway on host HERCULES / sapgw10                                                                           
> *  ERROR       partner 'hercules:sapgw01' not reached                                                                           
> *                                                                                                                               
> *  TIME        Thu Nov 24 09:10:20 2011                                                                                         
> *  RELEASE     701                                                                                                              
> *  COMPONENT   NI (network interface)                                                                                           
> *  VERSION     38                                                                                                               
> *  RC          -10                                                                                                              
> *  MODULE      nixxi.cpp                                                                                                        
> *  LINE        2835                                                                                                             
> *  DETAIL      NiPConnect2                                                                                                      
> *  SYSTEM CALL connect                                                                                                          
> *  ERRNO       10061                                                                                                            
> *  ERRNO TEXT  WSAECONNREFUSED: Connection refused                                                                              
> *  COUNTER     1385122                                                                                                          
> *                                                                                                                               
> *****************************************************************************
> ```

```
GwTraceHdlInfo:                                                                                                                 

HANDLE   = 137                                                                                                                  
TIME     = Thu Nov 24 09:10:19 2011                                                                                             
SOCKET   = 2108                                                                                                                 
STAT     = NI_CONN_WAIT                                                                                                         
TYPE     = STREAM IPv4                                                                                                          
OUT      = 0 messages 0 bytes                                                                                                   
IN       = 0 messages 0 bytes                                                                                                   
LOCAL    = 0.0.0.0:1865                                                                                                         
REMOTE   = -                                                                                                                    
OPTIONS  = BUFFERED                                                                                                             
  ni hdl           = 137                                                                                                        
  type             = CLIENT                                                                                                     
  net_stat         = CONNECT_TO_REM_GW_PENDING                                                                                  
  hostaddr         = 100.100.103.15                                                                                             
  accept_hostaddr  = 100.100.103.15                                                                                             
  opcode           = NORMAL_CLIENT                                                                                              
  conn opcode      = REMOTE_GATEWAY                                                                                             
  conn vers        = 2                                                                                                          
  index            = 10                                                                                                         
  data             = 0000000000000000                                                                                           
  ext_info         = 000000000EF1D870                                                                                           
  offset           = 0                                                                                                          
  rest_len         = 0                                                                                                          
  snc_forced       = 0                                                                                                          
 remote gateway infos:                                                                                                          
  hostname =                                                                                                                    
  hostaddr = 100.100.103.15                                                                                                     
  service  = sapgw01                                                                                                            
  tpname   = sapdp01                                                                                                            

GwSelClear: clear RWC for hdl 137                                                                                               
NiICloseHandle: called for hdl 137 while waiting for connection                                                                 
NiICloseHandle: shutdown and close hdl 137 / sock 2108                                                                          
GwFreeHdlInfoMemory: free 000000000EF1D870 (ext info)                                                                           
GwIFreeMemForLU_TP: freed memory for sys 10                                                                                     
GwListRemove: remove elem 10 from sys_r3_list                                                                                   
GwListRemove: 2 elems in sys_r3_list                                                                                            
GwListRemove: elem 10 not in sys_reg_list                                                                                       
GwListRemove: remove elem 10 from sys_inuse_list                                                                                
GwListRemove: 104 elems in sys_inuse_list                                                                                       
GwUpdateClient: act_sys: 104                                                                                                    
GwIDelR3Conn: send error message to client                                                                                      
GwSendRc3: send (appc_rc=CM_PRODUCT_SPECIFIC_ERROR / sap_rc=GW_CONNECT_FAILED) to client HERCULES / sapgw10 (0)                 
GwRqDpSendTo: (HERCULES / sapgw10, gw_id=0, appc_ca_blk=-1, len=335, comm_index=-1)                                             
LOCK APPC ca_blk 3                                                                                                              
DpGetCpicCommIdx: found index 3 via appc_hdr                                                                                    
found comm entry 3 (tid/uid/mode/conv_id/a_r: 158/13268/0/        /0)                                                           
GwIsAWaitingSWP: wp 1 waiting                                                                                                   
GwSapWpWakeUp: send answer to sap wp 1                                                                                          
GwSapWpWakeUp: make wp 1 owner of appc_ca_blk 3                                                                                 
-OUT- tid         -1            uid  -1           mode  255                                                                     
-OUT- appc_ca_blk 3             len  335          rq_id 43133                                                                   
-OUT- wait_f_answ 0             cmd  0                                                                                          

NiIWrite: hdl 109 sent data (wrt=28,pac=1,MESG_IO)                                                                              
GwIDelR3Conn: decrement conv_no of client 0: 5                                                                                  
GwFreeMemory: free 000000000EEF3480 (len=3700)                                                                                  
GwFreeMemory: act_overflow_size = 20352 (- 3700)                                                                                
GwIDelR3Conn: idx/conv = ((-1/0) | (10/0)), delete conv 48 from conv-table                                                      
GwClearConn: conv_no/tcp_conv_no/sna_conv_no: 6/6/0                                                                             
GwClearConn: free r3 conv info                                                                                                  
GwClearConn: free buffer info                                                                                                   
GwFiSearchConvId: deleted 27077110 local, conn=48                                                                               
GwListInsert: insert elem 48 into conn_free_list (at begin)                                                                     
GwListInsert: 494 elems in conn_free_list                                                                                       
GwListRemove: remove elem 48 from conn_search_list                                                                              
GwListRemove: 0 elems in conn_search_list                                                                                       
GwListRemove: elem 48 not in conn_write_list                                                                                    
GwListRemove: remove elem 48 from conn_inuse_list                                                                               
GwListRemove: 6 elems in conn_inuse_list                                                                                        
GwReadReqIndex: (process_id: -1)                                                                                                
GwReadReqIndex: no filled request-index-block                                                                                   
GwCheckClient: check clients                                                                                                    
LOCK APPC ca_blk 4                                                                                                              
GwCheckClient: raise timeout for conv 27059938 (intr/uid/mode/comm_idx=9/13261/0/90)                                            
GwSendRcToDp: send appc_rc/sap_rc 10001/221 to dp                                                                               
make DISP owner of appc_ca_blk 4                                                                                                
DpSemRq: key: 3, units: 1, timeout: -1                                                                                          
DpSemRel: key: 3, units: 1                                                                                                      
DpRqPutIntoQueue: put request into queue (reqtype 0, prio LOW, rq_id 43134)                                                     
GwDispWakeUp: send wakeup with ni handle 2                                                                                      
NiIWrite: hdl 2 sent data (wrt=1,pac=1,MESG_IO)                                                                                 
-OUT- sender_id APPC_SERVER       tid  165   wp_ca_blk   -1      wp_id -1                                                       
-OUT- action    SEND_TO_WP        uid  13261   appc_ca_blk 4       type  NOWP                                                   
-OUT- new_stat  NO_CHANGE         mode 0     len         80      rq_id 43134                                                    
GwListRemove: remove elem 90 from comm_wait_list                                                                                
GwListRemove: 0 elems in comm_wait_list                                                                                         
GwListRemove: remove elem 90 from comm_wait_list                                                                                
GwListRemove: 0 elems in comm_wait_list
```

**Edit 2: added code example**

I've created a little code example and if noticed that at the end one connection remains open. If I start the example again, two connections remain open at the end of the example.
So something is going wrong...

```
protected void SAP( object sender, EventArgs e ) {

    ThreadStart threadStart1 = new ThreadStart( CreateSAP );
    Thread thread = new Thread( threadStart1 );
    Thread thread2 = new Thread( threadStart1 );

    thread.Start();
    Thread.Sleep( 2000 );
    thread2.Start();

    while ( thread2.IsAlive ) {

    }

    Response.Write( "done" );
}

private void CreateSAP() {
    R3Connection conn = ERPConnection.Connection;
    conn.MultithreadingEnvironment = true;

    for ( int i = 0; i < 12; i++ ) {
        try {
            conn.Open();
            Thread.Sleep( 1000 );
        } finally {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please increase the gateway trace level (transaction SMGW), wait until the error occurs and post the corresponding log entries.

Comment: @vwegert: added an extract of the error log. I don't know if this is enough. It's not easy to find the exact error in the trace file.

Comment: Sorry, nothing obvious - I'd recommend creating a SAPnet message and let the experts have a look...

Comment: I think it has something to do with ERPConnect nothing closing the connection properly (or I don't implement it correctly). Unfortunately our support has expired and it's quite expensive to buy a new support package for this error only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it was something I did in my code which wasn't very... euh... nice.
ERPConnect has a R3Connection-object and I used a singleton throughout my whole application.

If a connection was in use by a user while another user also requested a connection, the R3Connection-object created a new connection (you can verify this by using the SM04-transaction in SAP).
If both users however closed the connection, one of the two connections remained open (I think this a bug in ERPConnect but we can't contact them because our support is expired for now).
The limit of connections (defined in SAP) is reached quickly off course in a production environment.

I now create a R3Connection-object for each user so I'm sure the connection is properly closed in the SAP-system when calling the Close() method (or using statement) in my code.

**Code**

```
public static R3Connection Connection {
        get {
            ERPConnect.LIC.SetLic( "MyLicenseKey" );

            R3Connection connection = new R3Connection( 
                        [set connection settings]
                     );
            connection.MultithreadingEnvironment = true;

            return connection;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you show me how you did that connection object for each connection?  I have a similar problem

Comment: @Nate I've added a code example. I hope it solves your problem!

Comment: hey thanks.  Theobald responded to this and said it's a bug in the librfcdll.  A new version is available here:http://my.theobald-software.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/54/9/useful-links

Answer (score 0):

I'm hunting around for the answer to a completely different problem, but seeing as I've stumbled across yours, this looks very much like network configuration - make sure that your SAP server "hercules" has ports 3210, 3310 and 3610 (I think those are right - might be 3201/3301/3601, tough to tell from SMGW logs) open in Windows Firewall, that there aren't any other firewalls blocking relevant traffic, and that the default gateway on "hercules" is set to a device which can successfully route traffic to 100.100.103.15 (I'm assuming, from your logs, that that's the IP address of your server on which the .NET application is running), and that the default gateway on 100.100.103.15 is set to a device which can successfully route traffic to "hercules". Furthermore, you'll have better luck if you use a fully qualified domain name (e.g. hercules.sap.local) to make the connection to your SAP server, because then you're no longer reliant on the prehistoric vagaries of NetBIOS to find your SAP server.

Comment: It was a problem in my code. The error indeed indicates a network problem and also searched in that direction for a long time...